# Why StreamHandler doesn't catch log messages?

Tags: java, logging

What is wrong with this code?

```
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import java.util.logging.StreamHandler;

Logger log = Logger.getLogger("foo");
log.setUseParentHandlers(false);
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
log.addHandler(new StreamHandler(baos, new SimpleFormatter()));
log.info("test");
assert baos.toByteArray().length > 0;
```

It fails since `baos` is empty. Why it's empty?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It requires flushing

```
Handler handler = new StreamHandler(outputStream, new SimpleFormatter());
log.addHandler(handler);
log.info("test");
handler.flush();
```

Now it's 44 bytes

By the way, enjoyed the books

Comment: works! Glad you like them! BTW, I would rename `streamHandler` to `handler` and declare it as `Handler` instead of `StreamHandler` :)

Comment: @yegor256 Yep, agree that's an improvement. I've made that edit